# Video presentation on RPi3 with SDL2

Tags: video, c++, sdl

I had successfully followed the [LazyFoo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) tutorials to basic shape/image rendering and am getting over 30 FPS on my RPi3.  My next stage is to get video file rendering working.  I had used the following code example but the video playback FPS is abysmal.

```
// sdltest.cpp
// Demonstrates how to play video with SDL2
// Source: http://www.programering.com/a/MTN5EzMwATY.html

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
// ffmpeg
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"

// SDL
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_thread.h>
};

#pragma comment(lib,"../lib/avutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"../lib/avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"../lib/avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"../lib/swscale.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"../lib/sdl2.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: <program> <video>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    const char* filename = argv[1];
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ffmpeg
    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    // Open video file
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    if( avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL) != 0 )
    {
        return -1; // Couldn't open file
    }

    // Retrieve stream information
    if( avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) <0 )
    {
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information
    }

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, filename, 0);
    // Find the first video stream
    int videoStream = -1;
    for(int i=0; i <pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if( pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO )
        {
          videoStream = i;
          break;
        }
    }
    if( videoStream == -1)
    {
        return -1; // Didn't find a video stream
    }

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    AVCodecContext * pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    AVCodec* pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    if( pCodec == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }

    // Open codec
    AVDictionary* optionsDict = NULL;
    if( avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict) < 0)
    {
        return -1; // Could not open codec
    }

    //Source color format
    AVPixelFormat src_fix_fmt = pCodecCtx->pix_fmt; //AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
    //Objective color format
    AVPixelFormat dst_fix_fmt = PIX_FMT_BGR24;
   // Allocate video frame
    AVFrame* pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVFrame* pFrameYUV = av_frame_alloc();
    if( pFrameYUV == NULL )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    struct SwsContext* sws_ctx = sws_getContext(
        pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
        pCodecCtx->width,
        pCodecCtx->height,
        dst_fix_fmt,
        SWS_BILINEAR,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(dst_fix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc( numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t) );

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameYUV, buffer, dst_fix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

    // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
    SDL_Rect sdlRect;
    sdlRect.x = 0;
    sdlRect.y = 0;
    sdlRect.w = pCodecCtx->width;
    sdlRect.h = pCodecCtx->height;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SDL
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER ))
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Window* sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Video Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, pCodecCtx->width,  pCodecCtx->height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if( !sdlWindow )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not set video mode - exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    SDL_Texture* sdlTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlRenderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGR24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
    if(!sdlTexture)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(sdlTexture,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND );

    AVPacket packet;
    SDL_Event event;
    while( av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
    {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if( packet.stream_index == videoStream)
        {
          // Decode video frame
          int frameFinished;
          avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

          // Did we get a video frame?
          if( frameFinished )
            {
             sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);

             SDL_UpdateTexture( sdlTexture, &sdlRect, pFrameYUV->data[0], pFrameYUV->linesize[0] );
             SDL_RenderClear( sdlRenderer );
             SDL_RenderCopy( sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, &sdlRect, &sdlRect );
             SDL_RenderPresent( sdlRenderer );
          }
          //SDL_Delay(50);
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
        av_free_packet(&packet);
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        switch( event.type )
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                SDL_Quit();
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(sdlTexture);

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_free(pFrame);
    av_free(pFrameYUV);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

I have been using all standard raspbian packages and the following Makefile

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs sdl2 SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_ttf` -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil

sdltest:
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o sdlapp sdltest.cpp $(LDFLAGS)
```

When run I do get the following message:

```
[swscaler @ 0x#####] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgr24.
```

Which is why I suspect some aspect is not running with hardware acceleration.
There are many video players which claim to use SDL to display and the few that I have tried all seem to perform playback at an acceptable FPS, so I strongly believe I can do it, I just can't seem to figure out the proper magic code.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was closer then I thought and the answer was a little counter to most of the recommendations.

The line:

```
SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
```

Was changed to:

```
SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
```

When running on Windows, the hardware acceleration gave best performance, but on the RPi3 the software render mode was superior.

Hopefully this will be useful for others.